# IP multicast support

Tags: ip, multicast

I am currently learning about IP multicast. I am confused what support mechanism it needs for it to be used. For e.g support from OS , Network cards etc ..

As per my understanding, IP multicast is supported when at least one of the network cards installed on the machine which desired to use IP multicast supports it. Also the routers on which the multicast traffic expected should support or enable the IP multIcasting

In other words, if there are many network cards installed on the machine and none of the network cards support multicast , can we say that IP multicast is not supported by the platform ?

How operating system involved in terms of  IP multicast support ? I mean to say, even if a network card supports IP multicast, does an OS have to support the IP multicast as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every host supports multicast, and every host already subscribes to the link-local All-Hosts multicast address (`224.0.0.1`).

Multicast is not up to the NIC, it is up to an application which want to listen to one or more multicast groups. Multicast is selective, and when you run an application which subscribes to a multicast group, then your network stack will listen for traffic with the destination address of that multicast group, and it will pass that traffic up to the subscribing application.

Comment: my question is for subscription and joining the group , should the application which is joining a group for listening to mulitcast traffic should have support to multicast, if so what kind of support, does application's OS should support mulitcast sockets, or NIC's installed on that machine should support  or both of the OS and NIC on the application should support the mullticast.

Comment: also to put in other way, if want to know that platform (OS)  supports the multicast, should OS have build in support or NICs on the OS support?

Comment: An application which doesn't support multicast would never ask to join a multicast group. Multicast is part of the IP network stack. The NICs have nothing to do with it since they are at a layer below IP. If your OS has IP in its network stack, it supports multicast.

Comment: ok,I understand that NIC's are part of data link layer, IP multicast is part of Internet layer, can you tell what do you mean by "your OS has IP" ? does it mean if it has TCP/IP protocol support (for e.g IP4 or IP6) ?

Comment: So as i am unfolding things, it seems like OS plays a key role in support of "multicast" , as "multicast" is a "mode" of communication it is linked to IP (internet) layer which in turn linked to the support that OS should give the machine in terms of IP4 or IP6 protocol.

So simply put, multicast should be dependent on OS .

is this correct ?

Comment: Yes. The OS network stack can have various network protocols, one of which could be the IPv4 and/or IPv6 stack. Others may be somethingthing like IPX. The NIC is actually in the Physical layer.

Comment: The OS plays a key role in any networking up through the transport layer. Multicast is dependent on IP support. The network stack is really part of the OS.

Comment: Ok it makes much sense, but there is something called NetworkInterface in java , which is a network card installed on a machine.
There is a method in that which says "supportsMulticast" , so that baffles me much because it says whether NIC supports multicast.

If you are not a java guy sorry :)

Comment: The NIC doesn't care about anything but the bits on the wire. The driver worries about the Data-Link layer. If it is an ethernet NIC, or any protocol which supports multicast at layer-2 (MAC addresses), then multicast is inherent in the ethernet layer-2 protocol.

Comment: you can see my confusion via here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#supportsMulticast()

Comment: I'm not a Java guy. You may want to ask about that on [so], where there are many network-savvy programmers.

Comment: ok so NIC have some role to play i quote you said 
"If it is an ethernet NIC, or any protocol which supports multicast at layer-2 (MAC addresses)," that essentially says layer 2 (data link layer) should support multicast.

Comment: No. the NIC is the physical layer. A driver for the NIC should implement the Data-Link layer. You are confusing network layers. For instance, ethernet is a series of protocols, some of which are concerned with the Physical layer, and some of which are concerned with the Data-Link layer. Ethernet supports multicast because it is built into MAC addressing for the Data-Link layer ethernet protocols.

Comment: I go through the wiki , it says  : "The NIC is both a physical layer and data link layer device, as it provides physical access to a networking medium and, for IEEE 802 and similar networks, provides a low-level addressing system through the use of MAC addresses that are uniquely assigned to network interfaces."

Comment: The problem with that idea is that you could create your own Data-Link layer for a NIC by writing your own driver for the NIC. It could use the ethernet Physical layer, but a completely different Data-Link layer which is not ethernet.

Comment: Ok, while i was going through the wiki it says 
" Although other network technologies exist, IEEE 802 networks including the Ethernet variants have achieved near-ubiquity since the mid-1990s. "

with your previous comment and from the wiki, This means that "Ethernet"  network standard which is universally used inherently supports multicast, right?

Comment: Ethernet inherently supports multicast at the Data-Link layer. The IP stack supports it at the Network layer. There are two different pieces to multicast network support. Your Data-Link layer must support it, not all Data-Link protocols do, and your Network layer must support it, too. GRE tunnels are used on devices (typically, not hosts) which connect with a Data-Link protocol which doesn't support multicast.